# Xpath how to use and statement and parent condition on a node selection

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have a XML like this:

```
<my-parent-tag attr="">
  <my-child-tag/>
</my-parent-tag>
<my-child-tag/> <!--I don't want to select this one-->
```

I want to find all my-child-tags that have the parent node my-parent-tag with attr="". How do I express this in Xpath? I tried

```
//my-child-tag and [../my-parent-tag[@attr='']]
```

But, I ended up getting Xpath-no-node-selected feedback. Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use regular expression `//parent/child`

Selects all descendant tags from parent with attribute:

```
//my-parent-tag[@attr='']//my-child-tag
```

Selects all child tags from parent with attribute:

```
//my-parent-tag[@attr='']/my-child-tag
```

Comment: That's *not* a regular expression, and your `//my-child-tag` will select all  `my-child-tag` descendants, not just children `my-child-tag` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `//my-child-tag[parent::my-parent-tag[@attr='']]`

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//my-parent-tag[@attr='']/my-child-tag
```

will select all `my-child-tag` elements with a parent of `my-parent-tag` that has a `attr` attribute value of `''`.